# Linux Bash scripting execute a terminal command on a list of filenames

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, terminal, shell-script

I have a file with a list of filenames that I am attempting to use as input in a specific file download tool (sratools) but my script has an issue

```
#!/bin/bash
input="<path_to_directory>/SRR_Acc_List.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do 
    "<path_to_tool>/fastq-dump -O <desired_output_directory/ $line"
    echo "Downloading $line file"
done <"$input"
```

The command is functional on a single input, and the echo is correct but the command portion throws the error

```
line 6: ./fastq-dump -O ../../DATA_fastQ/ SRR1975008: No such file or directory
```

I would appreciate pointers in where I have gone wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

> ```
> "<path_to_tool>/fastq-dump -O <desired_output_directory/ $line"
> ```

should be

```
"<path_to_tool>/fastq-dump" -O "<desired_output_directory/" "$line"
#       unquoted spaces    ^  ^     they separate words    ^
```

so there are four words. Your original line was quoted as a whole and interpreted as one word, a command name. Since your "command name" begins with `./`, it must be a file or directory. But there is no file or directory with the literal name `./fastq-dump -O ../../DATA_fastQ/ SRR1975008`, hence the error.

I quoted `<path_to_tool>/fastq-dump` and `<desired_output_directory/` just in case the actual values contain spaces and/or such. From the error message I can tell they don't, but in general they may.

It's very good you do quote (e.g. here: `done <"$input"`). The issue was you used one pair of quotes where certain strings had to be treated separately.